# How to remove code from external release

Tags: python, python-2.7

I want to release a subset of my code for external use. Only certain functions or methods should be used (or even seen) by the external customer. Is there a way to do this in Python?

I thought about wrapping the code I want removed in an `if __debug__:` and then creating a .pyc file with `py_compile` or `compileall` and then recreate source code from the new byte-code using `uncompyle2`. The `__debug__` simply creates an `if False` condition which gets stripped out by the "compiler". I couldn't figure out how to use those "compiler modules" with the `-O` option.

Comment: In Python, all attributes are open for inspection. Underscores are used to make things hidden, but only to code completion and other developers. Other devs know to interface with stuff that doesn't begin with an underscore.

Comment: If you're releasing a module, you're open sourcing the code, right? The bytecode for a given script that works in 3.2 may not work in 3.0 or 3.4. You need to provide your code, if people are to use it. Moreover, bytecode is execute-only; you can't import from it, and anyone can decompile it.

Comment: Yes, the code is open source, but it controls hardware. The internal only version exposes certain aspects of the hardware that we don't want the general public to know about. I guess my thought was that I would then use `uncompyle2` to create Python source code... I'll update my question to reflect that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if there are any standard tools for doing this, but it shouldn't be too difficult to mark the sections with appropriately coded remarks and then run all your files through a script that outputs a new set of files omitting the lines between those remarks.

Comment: Yeah, I wondered if that would be the best way to do it. Thanks for the answer!